# Looking for a book on optimizing tables and queries for handling time sequence data

Tags: time-series-database

I once had an electronic copy of what I understood to be a classic work on optimizing tables and queries for handling timestamped data.  It was old-ish when I found it 6-8 years ago.  I was sure I also printed and bound a copy but that disappeared in the move when I left my last job.

It was DBMS-agnostic and may be obsolete if standard SQL features and/or various vendor extensions have filled the hole it addressed.  However, now that I want it, I can't find it.

As an example of a question it helped answer was: if you record values only on change so your table says it was 75 degrees at noon and went up to 76 at 2pm, what was the temperature at 1pm?

I am *not* looking for answer to *that* question but I've Googled and Googled trying to find a new electronic copy and haven't come close.  Does this sound familiar to anyone here?  I'd appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding "out of print" to my search terms led to https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/02D8929E-1F0D-11D9-9830-000A95A0A9C8%40mit.edu which references https://www2.cs.arizona.edu/people/rts/tdbbook.pdf which is what I was looking for.